# Are reports of extreme koi lifespan real -- do they really live over 200 years?

Tags: koi, lifespan

I know that one of the chief problems with verifying the claims of extreme age for anything is that humans do not live, for example in the case of koi, anywhere near 200 years. And even if they did, no photographic evidence extends that far back. Moreover, extreme age in humans and animals has been an area where a lot of frankly lying has occurred simply because this increases interest in the person or fish.

There are ways of verifying the age of some animals as exceeding not just 200 years but in the case of the Greenland shark, some specimens may have reached 500 years!

So is it plausible that some Koi, which I understand continue to grow if they have food and a big enough enclosure throughout their lives, reach 200 or more years?

Comment: You wrote a lots of text, but I can not find a clear question in it. Please add a question, which is in scope of pets.SE!

Comment: They do not grow indefinitely. I have seen old Koi in professional ponds in Japan and I doubt any exceeded 42 in.  A Koi may out live a person, but then it is no longer that persons responsibility so not to worry.

Comment: this question is a better fit over at https://biology.stackexchange.com/